# pentaho local and remote connection to sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc, pentaho, sqljdbc

This is giving me headache.
I just set up pentaho community edition on my laptop. I was able to connect to mysql server in xampp by following the instructions in the pdf documentation that comes with the enterprise edition `getting_started_with_pentaho`. I connect perfectly to mysql database. 
However I need to also connect both locally and remotely to a sql server (mssql) but follwing the same process as i did for the mysql database does not work.
This is what i did:
I installed `SQLServer2008R2SP1-KB2528583-x64-ENU.exe` sql server and logged in successfully with the following input

```
server type: database engine
server name: ME-PC\SQLEXPRESS
authentication: windows authentication
login: ME-PC\ME
password:
```

Now I downloaded the jdbc driver for mssql from [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/2/A/02AAE597-3865-456C-AE7F-613F99F850A8/sqljdbc_4.0.2206.100_enu.exe) and extracted the folder to my desktop. The folder contained `sqljdbc4.jar` and `sqljdbc.jar` as well as both x64 and x86 versions of `sqljdbc_auth.dll`.

I am running a x64 OS but but the jdk i installed went to the Programfiles(x86) so I guess the java i had install was for x86. Due to this reason I copied `sqljdbc4.jar` and the x86 version of `sqljdbc_auth.dll` to the directorys:

`C:\Users\ELRAPHA\Desktop\PENTAHO\biserver-ce\tomcat\webapps\pentaho\WEB-INF\lib`

`C:\Users\ELRAPHA\Desktop\PENTAHO\administration-console\jdbc`

`C:\Users\ELRAPHA\Desktop\PENTAHO\data-integration\libext\JDBC`

I also enabled TCI/IP on my local sql server.

As I mentioned, am able to connect to sql server via the management studio but when i try to create a new connection through pentaho in the web browser with the following

```
hostname: localhost
database name: master
instance name: ME-PC\SQLEXPRESS
port: 1433
username: ME-PC\ME
password:
```

I get the error

error connecting to database [mssqllocal]
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

error connecting to database:(using class com.microsoft.sqlserver.JDBC.SqlServerDriver)
The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed.
Error: Connection refused: connect.

I dont get what am doing wrongly especially since mysql was to straight forward. Been at this all day. I need help . Please can anyone see my error or something that am missing here? HELP

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect through JDBC to SQL Server via Windows Authentication, then the sqljdbc_auth.dll must be in the right location. On my system (x86) that this is relative to the install directory of the sqljdbc4 driver. By *"extracted the folder to my desktop"* I assume you mean you ran the installer, and that's where you choose the location of the driver. For example on my system, this file is not in the Pentaho folders, it's in:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x86
```

I would ensure that both 32 and 64 bit versions of sqljdbc_auth.dll are in their respective locations since you seem to have a mixed system.

Alternatively, you can use SQL Server authentication which is simpler, but doesn't integrate with AD, etc.

EDIT:

Oops, I forgot something very important. The JVM must be made aware of the location of sqljdbc_auth.dll. I had to add the path of that dll to %LIBSPATH% in Spoon.bat (I'm only using PDI).

So essentially I changed this block of code in the batch file:

```
:USE32
REM ===========================================
REM Using 32bit Java, so include 32bit SWT Jar
REM ===========================================
set LIBSPATH=libswt\win32
GOTO :CONTINUE
:USE64
REM ===========================================
REM Using 64bit java, so include 64bit SWT Jar
REM ===========================================
set LIBSPATH=libswt\win64
set SWTJAR=..\libswt\win64
```

to this:

```
:USE32
REM ===========================================
REM Using 32bit Java, so include 32bit SWT Jar
REM ===========================================
set LIBSPATH=libswt\win32;C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.0FO\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x86
GOTO :CONTINUE
:USE64
REM ===========================================
REM Using 64bit java, so include 64bit SWT Jar
REM ===========================================
set LIBSPATH=libswt\win64
set SWTJAR=..\libswt\win64
```

Note the shortened path names. In your case, I would add an entry for the 64 bit lib also since you have a mixed environment.

Essentially whatever program you're starting that uses the sqljdbc driver, you must add the path the sqljdbc_auth.dll to the Java library path (i.e. `-Djava.library.path=%LIBSPATH%`). After doing that, my instance of PDI can connect to SQL Server via Windows Authentication with no trouble. I don't use the BI_Server or the Admin Console, but I suspect you'll have the same issue.

Note, I have no experience with SQLEXPRESS, or a mixed 32 bit JVM/64 bit OS environment. There could be problems there too, but if you want to use Windows Authentication with SQL Server, you have to at least deal with the library path issue.

Comment: This is not the actual problem in the question.

Comment: @Brian.D.Myers Actually I thought it would be better to put sqljdbc4.dll into the respective directories instead of modifying the bat file. However I think the problem is my local server because am able to connect to a remote sql server. The local one is the problem. The error seems to be about TCP/IP. But i have enables it locally so am stuck on what to do

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you can connect to and with what. You're saying you can in fact connect to the remove SQL Server instance with Pentaho? When you said management studio, I thought you meant Enterprise Management Studio. Which one is it? And where is Pentaho server running from?

Comment: @Brian.D.Myers I have pentaho on my local machine as well as sql server express management studio. The pentaho i have can connect to a remote sql server  i have but it cannot connect to my local sql server. I keep getting the error `Server=ELRAPHA-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=logTester;User Id=sa; Password=pass;`. So then i wrote a piece of code in visual studio to connect to the local sql server with the conn string `connectionString="Server=ME-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Tester;User Id=user; Password=pass;"` and it connected. Since am able to connect throu visual studio I dnt get the TCP/IP error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a intance of Sql Express in local machine and connecting Pentaho, you must **empty** the field **Port Number**. Try the configuration below:

```
Host Name: localhost  
Database: database_name  
Instance Name: sqlexpress 
Port Number:  
User Name: user_name  
Password: *****
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of having issues, together with empty the port number, is to manually set the instance name as a manual parameter:

```
instanceName=SQLEXPRESS
```

The default pentaho dialog (at least to 8.3) generates only the code "instance=SQLEXPRESS"